# Strange result when calculating with mysql dates

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-arithmetic

This calculation
`select cast('2016-06-01 00:00:00' as datetime)-cast('2016-05-31 00:00:00' as datetime)`
has as result 70 000 000 in mySQL.

I'm aware that I should not use that contruction, but I'm curious what the 70000000 is?

Comment: There are `86 400 000` milliseconds in the time period you subtracted.  I have no idea where the `70` million is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that is not how dates or datetimes are substracted. One uses `datediff` and `timediff` for that. Just saying. So see MySQL [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

But looking at

```
select cast('2016-06-01 00:00:00' as datetime)-cast('2016-05-31 00:00:00' as datetime);
```

70000000

```
select cast('2016-06-01 00:00:00' as datetime)-cast('2016-05-30 00:00:00' as datetime);
```

71000000

```
select cast('2016-06-01 00:00:00' as datetime)-cast('2016-06-02 00:00:00' as datetime);
```

-1000000

```
select cast('2016-06-01 00:00:00' as datetime)-cast('123' as char(3) );
```

20160600999877;

One can see a pattern of them being treated as bigints. So

```
select  20160601000000 - 20160531000000;
```

70000000

```
select  20160601000000 - 20160530000000;
```

71000000

So that would seem to be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816093/drew) indicates, when performing subtraction are treated as BIGINT:

```sql
$ mysql --column-type-info

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `der`.`DATE_1`,
    ->   `der`.`DATE_2`,
    ->   `der`.`DATE_1` - `der`.`DATE_2` DIFF
    -> FROM (SELECT CAST('2016-06-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) `DATE_1`,
    ->              CAST('2016-05-31 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) `DATE_2`) `der`;
Field   1:  `DATE_1`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      `der`
Org_table:  ``
Type:       DATETIME
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     19
Max_length: 19
Decimals:   0
Flags:      BINARY 

Field   2:  `DATE_2`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      `der`
Org_table:  ``
Type:       DATETIME
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     19
Max_length: 19
Decimals:   0
Flags:      BINARY 

Field   3:  `DIFF`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     16
Max_length: 8
Decimals:   0
Flags:      BINARY NUM 

-- 20160601000000       20160531000000
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| DATE_1              | DATE_2              | DIFF     |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | 2016-05-31 00:00:00 | 70000000 |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Ah, a much finer answer. Good job.